# PHP and SQL table in HTML

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to find a way to display a table from SQL in HTML in this way as I have shown below in the html part:

**Html**

```
 <table>
    <tr>
    <td><a><img src="" width=135 height=100/></a></td>
    <td><a><h2>Title</h2></a><p>DDMMYY</p><p>Description</p></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

My current script only outputs the result in one line, like this:

**PHP**

```
<?php    
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT title, tag, desc FROM Tbl1;'); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo "<table>";
    foreach($res AS $val) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach($val AS $val1) {
            echo "<td>$val1</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    $db = null;
?>
```

Comment: Try to debug your script by `var_dump` first.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT title, tag, `desc` FROM Tbl1;');
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
echo '<table>';
for($results as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['imagefield'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td style="text-align: right">' . $row['description'] . '<br />' . $text . '</td>';
    // etc...
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

There is no reason why this code wouldn't show a valid table.

Comment: But perhaps you did not see my problem? I want image to the left, and text to the right starting in the upper corner. The script places the image and text in one line. I want the title, description and author to be placed to the right of the image starting in the upper right corner as the html code i provided

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question... I have updated my answer.